# image classifier throws [ERROR] map operation: [Decode] failed how do i fix it

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm learning Vision Transformer, following a [tutorial](https://www.mindspore.cn/tutorials/application/en/r2.1/cv/vit.html)

I went through the content, ran the code, everything seemed good.

Then i randomly pick an image from [google results](https://pixabay.com/photos/cock-rooster-chicken-bird-poultry-7182845/), saved it to my disk, ran the model with it and then i got the error [ERROR] map operation: [Decode] failed

[image]

How do i fix it?

Here is the full crash log

```
[ERROR] MD(41922,0x28068b000,python):2023-10-17-17:19:56.259.811 [mindspore/ccsrc/minddata/dataset/util/task_manager.cc:223] InterruptMaster] Task is terminated with err msg (more details are in info level logs): Exception thrown from dataset pipeline. Refer to 'Dataset Pipeline Error Message'. map operation: [Decode] failed. The corresponding data file is: ./datasets/hw/dataset/infer/n01440764/._ILSVRC2012_test_00000279.JPEG. Decode: image decode failed.
Line of code : 362
File         : mindspore/ccsrc/minddata/dataset/kernels/image/image_utils.cc

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[14], line 144
    140     return mapping
    143 # Read data for inference
--> 144 for i, image in enumerate(dataset_infer.create_dict_iterator(output_numpy=True)):
    145     image = image["image"]
    146     image = ms.Tensor(image)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mindspore/dataset/engine/iterators.py:145, in Iterator.__next__(self)
    142     raise RuntimeError("Iterator does not have a running C++ pipeline.")
    144 # Note offload is applied inside _get_next() if applicable since get_next converts to output format
--> 145 data = self._get_next()
    146 if not data:
    147     if self.__index == 0:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mindspore/dataset/engine/iterators.py:270, in DictIterator._get_next(self)
    268     logger.critical("Memory error occurred, process will exit.")
    269     os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGKILL)
--> 270 raise err

File ~/anaconda3/envs/python39/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mindspore/dataset/engine/iterators.py:253, in DictIterator._get_next(self)
    251 try:
    252     if self.offload_model is None:
--> 253         return {k: self._transform_md_to_output(t) for k, t in self._iterator.GetNextAsMap().items()}
    254     data = [self._transform_md_to_tensor(t) for t in self._iterator.GetNextAsList()]
    255     if data:

RuntimeError: Exception thrown from dataset pipeline. Refer to 'Dataset Pipeline Error Message'. 

------------------------------------------------------------------
- Dataset Pipeline Error Message: 
------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] map operation: [Decode] failed. The corresponding data file is: ./datasets/hw/dataset/infer/n01440764/._ILSVRC2012_test_00000279.JPEG. Decode: image decode failed.

------------------------------------------------------------------
- C++ Call Stack: (For framework developers) 
------------------------------------------------------------------
mindspore/ccsrc/minddata/dataset/kernels/image/image_utils.cc(362).
```